laravel filament не пускает в админку
Всем привет! я новичок в laravel, но по работе прилетел проект, поэтому вынужден обратиться за помощью.
Имеется проект на laravel 8 с кастомной админкой, с заказчиком согласовали замену кастомной админки на админку от filament. на данный момент я вырезал старую админку, обновил laravel до 10 версии по документации с официального сайта.
Так же установил filament, создал для него пользователя, в системе появились связанные с ним роуты 
но при переходе на url http://127.0.0.1/admin я вижу, что:

Не загружаются файлы js и css для формы входа в админку (php artisan filament:assets прописал) из-за чего форма выглядит так 

при попытке входа в админку, получаю ошибку The POST method is not supported for route admin/login. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.


Сам по себе роутинг на проекте работает очень странно, в RouteServiceProvider в настройках для web.php указано следующее
Route::prefix('admin')->as('admin.')->middleware('web')->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
но если попробовать заменить префикс на какой либо другой, например 'test' и перейти по url http://127.0.0.1/test/test, получаю такую ошибку:

и такая ошибка всплывает абсолютно для всех префиксов кроме "admin". Почему так работает, я не понимаю. Я думаю из-за этого криво работает и сама админка, просьба подсказать в какую сторону хотя бы копать, буду очень благодарен, спасибо!
